# Can equivalence relations be axiomatized using just one elementary sentence?

Tags: model-theory, equivalence-relations

Equivalence relations are traditionally axiomatized by the Reflexivity, Symmetry, and Transitivity axioms. However, they can also be axiomatized by Reflexivity and Circularity. (Circularity is this axiom: $(xRy \land yRz) \rightarrow zRx$). I am wondering if we can make do with just one elementary sentence. By elementary sentence, I mean either an atomic formula, or a negated atomic formula, or finite disjunctions of the previous two. For example, Circularity can be rewritten as $(\neg xRy \vee \neg yRz \vee zRx)$, which is an elementary sentence by my definition. If it can't be axiomatized by just one elementary sentence, I want to see a proof that it can't be so axiomatized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is: this is not possible.

I'll assume that our non-logical vocabulary is exactly $\{R\}$.

Let $F$ denote the always-false binary relation and $T$ denote the always true binary relation.

#### Lemma 101: If $\varphi$ is negation-free, then $\varphi$ cannot require $R$ to be transitive without requiring it to be $T$.

Suppose $\varphi$ is negation-free.

If $\varphi$ is of the form $xRx$, then $R$ must be a superset of the identity relation. This does not require $R$ to be transitive.

If $\varphi$ is of the form $xRy$, then $R$ must be $T$. This requires $R$ to be transitive, but misses out on the identity relation, which is a potential equivalence relation that we need to allow.

For the general case, if $\varphi$ is negation-free, then, for any $S$ satisyfing $\varphi$ any superset $S' \supset S$ will also satisfy $\varphi$. Therefore, all the relations satisyfing $\varphi$ are transitive if any only if the only relation satisyfing $\varphi$ is $T$.

End of Lemma 101.

#### Lemma 102: If $\varphi$ contains negation, then it allows $F$

Suppose $\varphi$ contains at least one negated clause $\lnot xRy$ where $x$ and $y$ are not necessarily distinct.

If $R$ is $F$, then $xRy$ will always be false and hence $\varphi$ will vacuously be true.

End of Lemma 102.

##### Theorem: Equivalence Relations cannot be axiomatized using an elementary sentence.

No elementary sentence can be both negation-free and contain a negation, however, by Lemmas 101 and 102, we need both kinds of sentences in order to insist on transitivity without insisting that we have $T$ and to rule out $F$.

---

#### EDIT 2023-04-09: Correcting the addendum.

The sentence $\forall x \forall y \; (f(x) = f(y) \to xRy)$ does **NOT** axiomatize an equivlance relation.

For example, consider:

- $f = \{(0, 0), (1, 1)\}$ i.e. *$f$ is like the identity function*
- $R = \{(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)\}$ i.e. *$R$ is like material implication.*

I meant to say $\forall x \forall y \; (f(x) = f(y) \leftrightarrow xRy)$ with a biconditional, but expressing this requires **two** elementary sentences not one.

I don't know whether a single elementary sentence in the language with signature $(R, f)$ can axiomatize equivalence relations or not.