# Can strict partial orders be axiomatized using just one elementary sentence?

Tags: model-theory, order-theory

This is a follow-up to my previous question, here: [Can equivalence relations be axiomatized using just one elementary sentence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590299/can-equivalence-relations-be-axiomatized-using-just-one-elementary-sentence). Referring back to that question, I define an elementary sentence to be an atomic formula, a negated atomic formula, or finite disjunctions of the previous two. Now, strict partial orders can be axiomatized using the two elementary sentences $\neg xRx$ and $\neg xRy \vee \neg yRz \vee xRz$, which are, respectively, Anti-reflexivity and Transitivity. I am wondering if we can axiomatize strict partial orders using just one elementary sentence. If we can't, what is the proof we can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Minor quibble: when you define "elementary sentence," stricty speaking you are conflating a **formula** with its **universal closure**. This is a fairly common abuse of terminology, so I'm just going to follow it in the rest of this answer, but it's worth being aware of.*

The same basic idea as in [my answer to another question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4669152/28111) gives a negative answer here. Suppose $\varphi$ is an elementary sentence true only in strict partial orders. Then none of the disjuncts of $\varphi$ can be *un-negated* instaces of $R$, since otherwise $\varphi$ would be true in any structure where $R$ is interpreted as the total relation (= holding of all pairs). However, this means that if $(X;R)\models\varphi$ and $S\subseteq R$ then $(X;S)\models\varphi$ as well, since in passing from $R$ to $S$ we only ever make more disjuncts of $\varphi$ true for any particular variable assignment. But now consider e.g. $X=\{a,b,c\}$, $R=\{(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)\}$, and $S=\{(a,b),(b,c)\}$. Since $(X;S)$ is not transitive, it is not a strict partial order, and so we must have $(X;S)\not\models\varphi$ and hence $(X;R)\not\models\varphi$.

So any elementary sentence true in *only* the strict partial orders must be false in *at least some* (indeed, quite a lot of) structures which are not strict partial orders.